# The program in the computer

Tags: pattern

*An easy puzzle for beginners:*

You are in front of a computer which, upon your input, will produce a sequence of numbers. Your task is to discover which logic was used to program the computer.

Sitting in front of the computer, you type: 7. 
The computer replies with the sequence: 5, 4, 4, 4, and then 4 all along.

Then you type 6. 
The computer replies with: 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, and then 4 all along.

Pensive, you type 42. 
Computer's reply: 8, 5, 4, 4, 4, and then 4 all along again.

You try different numbers, and notice that all sequences eventually go with 4 repeated endlessly.

What is the algorithm used?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each sequence is generated by:

> Taking the number of letters in the spelling of the last number

I.E.

> 7=S-E-V-E-N has 5 letters
>  5=F-I-V-E has 4 letters
>  4=F-O-U-R has 4 letters....

Also Note

> Four is the only number that has the same number of letters as the number itself.

Comment: You were so quick in answering. Kudos, and yes, there's a sierpinski triangle there :-)

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: I just happened to log on right after this question was posted. It's pretty rare for me to get first on one like this.